# any alternative to overriding "equals()" method in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, equals

I have several very large ArrayLists of objects which i would like to find their Symmetric Differences ( or disjunction). To do so i have decided to use Sets and their "contain()" methods. However, this method uses the equals() method to evaluate said objects.
Problem is, i cannot make any changes in my class. So, i cannot override any method. (my code is just a small part of a very bigger project)

so this leaves me here, is there any other alternative to altering the classes themselves ? or any other way that would not require me to make any changes to my classes ?

Comment: You could implement a wrapper class.

Comment: You could put a wrapper class around each object and put whatever you want in the equals method of the wrapper class.

Comment: would a `Map<WhateverYourIDIs, YourObject>` be an option?

Comment: You need to compare the objects to state they're the same or not. On what basis do you think this can be done? Are they the same objects, namely?

Comment: If you use a `TreeSet`, you can pass in a `Comparator` that will be used instead of `equals`: [`TreeSet(Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-) But if the `Comparator` is at odds with the `equals` of the objects in the set, you'll asking `TreeSet` to violate the `Set` contract, details in `TreeSet`'s JavaDoc. It's behavior in that case is well-defined, but violates the semantics defined by `Set`. For that reason, I'd look at wrappers as noted by Oliver and khelwood.

Comment: I would use a wrapper class, as noted by Oliver and khelwood, just commented to add that you can use the method removeAll() instead of contains.

Comment: Thanks guys. a wrapper class would certainly do the trick. However, I was hoping for something like `Comparator` for arraylist or sets without the hassle. But i think im gonna go with the wrapper since it seems what im looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe write it into an answer and accept it so it can help others?

Comment: @RayO'Kalahjan Ofcourse. but first I will wait some time for the guys who first mentioned it since they deserve the credit.

Comment: I have recently discovered some new Java8 functionalities that can come in handy for this problem. I've posted a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently found out about this so I have an alternate solution (only for Java 8):

```java
// Being T the class of the objects in the list
ArrayList<T> list1 = ...;
ArrayList<T> list2 = ...;

// A function to compare two elements
BiFunction<T, T, Boolean> funcEquals = (a,b) -> yourEquals(a,b);
// A function that given a List returns a predicate that states if an element is on that list
Function<List<T>, Predicate<T>> notIn = (s) -> (e) -> s.stream().filter((y) -> funcEquals.apply(e, y)).count() == 0;

// Get the elements in list1 that are not in list2
Stream<String> list1Filtered = list1.stream().filter(notIn.apply(list2));
// Get the elements in list2 that are not in list1
Stream<String> list2Filtered = list2.stream().filter(notIn.apply(list1));
/*
If you have more than two lists, comparisons can be concatenated:
Stream<String> list1Filtered = list1.stream().filter(notIn.apply(list2)).filter(notIn.apply(list3));
Stream<String> list2Filtered = list2.stream().filter(notIn.apply(list1)).filter(notIn.apply(list3));
Stream<String> list3Filtered = list3.stream().filter(notIn.apply(list1)).filter(notIn.apply(list2));
*/

// Add them all together
ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
result.addAll(list1Filtered.collect(Collectors.toList()));
result.addAll(list2Filtered.collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

It's a little confusing at first, but you don't have to create any more classes.

Comment: even though i'm pretty sure that this way is not as effiecient as using a set ( O(N^K) to be more precise) im going to select it as the best answer for the creative use of the streams. and because i just hate overriding the `equals()` even with wrappers and i think it should only be done as a last resort. Thanks.

Comment: instead of `.filter(...).count() == 0` you can use `.noneMatch(...)`

Comment: I'd personally write `notIn` as a regular method taking a `List<T>` and returning a `Predicate<T>`.  Then you can just call it instead of `.apply(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a wrapper class, originally suggested by "Oliver Charlesworth" and other people in the comments.